# Form get data from Data Base (servlet+Jsp)

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

In my form, I have a a select option like this:

http://zaielacademic.net/java_jsp_servlets_mysql/forms_sticky_all.htm

But I have also a function `onchange`. How can I use it with this code?
I get the value selected from the servlet. I think I must use another function (`onselect`)?

```
<select name="situation" id="type"   class="form-control i9" >
   <option value="cle" <% if (proSituation.equals("cle")) out.print("selected"); %> >Célibataire</option>
   <option value="marie" <% if (proSituation.equals("marie")) out.print("selected"); %> >Marié</option>
   <option value="div" <% if (proSituation.equals("div")) out.print("selected"); %> >Divorcé</option>
   <option value="veuf" <% if (proSituation.equals("veuf")) out.print("selected"); %> >Veuf</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your real question. not clear what you ask. do you want to know how to access the selected drop down value in servlet?

Answer (score 0):

if the select value is "marie" then they call function

```
onchange="SituationFalilliale(this.value)

   function  SituationFalilliale(selection) {
```

switch(selection)
   { 
       case 'marie':
           $('#conjoint').show();
           break;
       default:
           $('#conjoint').hide();
           break;
   }

}

it is ok with onchange 
but i want is auto show it if value is "marie" not with onchange